# Use FreeMarker Template in Spring Boot with nested XML template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

So i have the below template for FreeMarker :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<master>
    <header>
        <version>${version}</version>
        <created>${created}</created>
        <creator>${creator}</creator>
        <draw>${draw}</draw>
        <game>${game}</game>
        <type>${type}</type>
        <sender>${sender}</sender>
        <recipient>${recipient}</recipient>
        <revision>${revision}</revision>
    </header>
    <data>
        <stake>
        ${stake}
        </stake>
        <checksum_combifile>
        ${checksumFile}
        </checksum_combifile>
    </data>
</master>
```

And the below POJO for FreeMarker Template :

```
public class SscMessageVo {

    /* Header */
    private String version = "1.00";
    private String created;
    private String creator;
    private String draw;
    private String game;
    private String type;
    private String sender;
    private String recipient;
    private String revision;

    /* Data */
    private String stake;
    private String checksumFile;

    public SscMessageVo() {
        super();
    }

    public SscMessageVo(final String version, final String created, final String creator, final String draw, final String game, final String type, final String sender, final String recipient,
        final String revision, final String stake, final String checksumFile) {
        super();
        this.version = version;
        this.created = created;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.draw = draw;
        this.game = game;
        this.type = type;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.revision = revision;
        this.stake = stake;
        this.checksumFile = checksumFile;
    }

    public String getStake() {

        return stake;
    }

    public void setStake(final String stake) {

        this.stake = stake;
    }

    public String getChecksumFile() {

        return checksumFile;
    }

    public void setChecksumFile(final String checksumFile) {

        this.checksumFile = checksumFile;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(final String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(final String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(final String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public String getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }

    public void setDraw(final String draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }

    public String getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(final String game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(final String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(final String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(final String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

}
```

All good all sweet and happy but now i want to do the below thing do avoid duplicate because i have many templates with the same header structure , move the variables that belong to header to a new class named **TemplateHeader** , like this :

```
public class TemplateHeader {

    /* Header */
    private String version;
    private String created;
    private String creator;
    private String draw;
    private String game;
    private String type;
    private String sender;
    private String recipient;
    private String revision;

    public TemplateHeader() {
        super();
    }

    public TemplateHeader(String version, String created, String creator, String draw, String game, String type, String sender, String recipient, String revision) {
        super();
        this.version = version;
        this.created = created;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.draw = draw;
        this.game = game;
        this.type = type;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public String getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }

    public void setDraw(String draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }

    public String getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(String game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

}
```

But i have no clue how to do that i am getting errors from FreeTemplate and can't find any tutorial on the web ....

Comment: It's not clear what did you try after separating the header fields. How the data-model (template context) looks? What did you expect, and what error you get?

Comment: @ddekany The template is exactly the same. I just want to separste the header values on another class :)

Comment: So instead of inheritance (`SscMessageVo  extends TemplateHeader`), you want to use composition, which is not transparent in the Java API, but you want this to be transparent for the template? That's possible as far as FreeMarker is concerned, you just need to create a custom `TemplateHashModel` implementation that delegates to two other `TemplateHashModel`-s (to the `config.getObjectWrapper().wrap(...)`-ed header bean, and to the similarly wrapped non-header bean). Unless Spring itself supports creating the model from the union of two beans.

Comment: @ddekany Well waitt if i extend TemplateHeader it will work for real?

Comment: @ddekany Please can you post an answer i will accept it ♡

Comment: Of course Java inheritance works. Added this as answer as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance (`SscMessageVo` extends `TemplateHeader`). Note that both classes and the getter methods has to be public.

If you want to use composition, it's trickier if that's not transparent in the Java API (as in `myComposite.getHeader().getCreator()`). But it can be transparent in the template. **Updated:** Simply create your data-model like 
`TemplateModelUtils.wrapAsHashUnion(config.getObjectWrapper(), myHeader, myData)`, where `myHeader` and `myData` are the object you want to "compose".

But, `TemplateModelUtils.wrapAsHashUnion` only exists since 2.3.29 (far from being released as of 2018-09-12). So meanwhile, check the source code (https://github.com/apache/freemarker/blob/2.3-gae/src/main/java/freemarker/template/utility/TemplateModelUtils.java). Yours can be much much simpler though. You just need something like `var ow = cfg.getObjectWrapper(); TemplateHashModel dataModel = new HashUnionModel(ow.wrap(myHeader), ow.wrap(myData));` Then use `dataModel` as your data-model.

Comment: I will use yout first paragraph eith Inheritance... though i want to see some code for the solution discribed on the other paragraph because i don't understand nothing :). Then i will accept happily your answer :)

Comment: Please can i have some code for composition ? I am trying really hard to understand it :'(

Comment: Can you guide me to a tutorial or something for the second solution , it's very important for my project :) . Take ma money boss !

Comment: As this is was needed for some other users too earlier, I decide to add an utility to FreeMarker 2.3.29 for this. See my comment.

Comment: Read the code , still too complex to understand how to use it . I am sorry for that trying ma best ...

Comment: Sorry, my example code at the end of my answer has missed some pieces... see it now. As you will see, you only need to copy `HashUnionModel` (before 2.3.29), which is a rather simple class. (Also, no, I'm not the original author of FreeMarker, though I do most of the maintenance for a good while now.)

Comment: Thank you :) last wish now .. Can you add two classes that specifically solve this problem ... like two classes like i have added on the question .  Like a future user coming here will not understand nothing . And i swear if i don't see classes i can't really understand what you mean . Please add java code with classes . Even two minimalistic classes . I don't understand other way , that's what i am trying to tell you politely on the other comments ... It is like i am reading Chinese .

Comment: I see `TemplateModelUtils.wrapAsHashUnion(config.getObjectWrapper()` and i am like whaaaaattttttt . Do it and i will accept this as an answer . I love you too.

Comment: Currently, at some place you pass an `SscMessageVo` object to Spring (there are multiple ways of that) to be the data-model (aka. template context). Right? At the sample place, instead of the `SscMessageVo` object you pass `new HashUnionModel(ow.wrap(myHeader), ow.wrap(myData))`. That's it. Therefore, you only need to implement one new class, `HashUnionModel`, and you can see that class on Github already.

Comment: Hello , any plans for new release :) ? I started using today your class for very complex xmls .... currently crying loud .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS In late december there should be one... ideally. Not sure what are you looking for though, as you are already using my class as you said.

Comment: :) I uploaded a small example of complex xml template i am working on ... how can i approach this instead of creating a lot of classes for FreeTemplate :) I appreciate your help so much .. https://github.com/goxr3plus/SprinBoot_FreeTemplate/blob/master/bankfile.ftl

Comment: That template didn't help me to understand the problem. In what format and from what source the data comes from, for which you don't want to create those lot of classes (bean classes for you data-model I assume).